# Can you retrieve rows using the keyword 'LIMIT' in SQL Express 2008?

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-express, sql-limit

I want to do this but SQL Express 2008 does not like the 'LIMIT' part.

```
select * 
from dbo.Message 
where AppType='WSBackup' 
order by MessageID desc
Limit 5
```

Comment: Check the manual, the correct syntax is documented there: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The SQL-Server equivalent of `limit` is `top`, at least for the simple, one-argument usecase:

```
SELECT   TOP 5 * 
FROM     dbo.Message 
WHERE    AppType = 'WSBackup'
ORDER BY MessageID DESC
```